# C++ / Visual Studio - How to output to Test Output Window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I'm aware of the logger in Visual Studio, i.e.:

```
Logger::WriteMessage("foo");
```

This works great for the test code, less practical for the code inside the application.  So, I'm looking for a standard solution to redirect the stdout messages inside the code.

Comment: What do you mean by `the screen'? I mean stdout messages normally appear in a console window, how is that different from the screen?

Comment: I'm looking at the "Output" + "Tests" window inside Visual Studio.

Comment: You can use Windows' [OutputDebugString function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx) to send output to the debugger, if any. To redirect `std::cout` you can replace its output buffer.

Comment: But I'd still have to replace all the "cout"s by a call to "OutputDebugStringW"... right?

Comment: @KlingonJoe: No, you replace the `streambuf` inside `cout`, once.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks!  I was able to reroute cout to a stringstream, and the print the string inside the stream.

Comment: @MSalters, Do you know how to get the buffer to the Logger class in Visual Studio unit testing?  I tried Logger and OutputDebugString... but neither class exposes a buffer.

Comment: @KlingonJoe: No idea. Besides, that seems to be an entirely different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stream in std-out can be reassigned, for example:

```
// REDIRECT STD STREAM
streambuf * backup;
backup = cout.rdbuf();
stringstream ss;
cout.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());    

// DO SOMETHING
cout << "foo\n";

// PRINT STREAM TO LOGGER
Logger::WriteMessage(ss.str().c_str());

// ASSIGN COUT BACK TO STDOUT
cout.rdbuf(backup);
```